# How to open/close ExpandableCalendar of react-native-calendars programmatically?

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

I want to open/close ExpandableCalendar programmatically. I found there's only an `initialPosition` prop. It's not working when changing `initialPosition`. So I tried to use ref and call `setPosition()` function of ExpandableCalendar

```js
export const MyScreen = () => {
  const ref = useRef<ExpandableCalendar>()

  return (
      <CalendarProvider date={new Date()}>
          <ExpandableCalendar ref={ref} />
      </CalendarProvider>
  )
}
```

when I use this code, the `ref.current.contentRef` is always `undefined`

### My Question is

- How to get the `ref` of ExpandableCalendar?
  It seems the `asCalendarConsumer` saves the ref as contentRef:

```js
function asCalendarConsumer(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<any>
): React.ComponentClass {
  class CalendarConsumer extends Component {
    contentRef: any;

    saveRef = (r: Ref<React.Component<any>>) => {
      this.contentRef = r;
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <CalendarContext.Consumer>
          {(context) => (
            <WrappedComponent
              ref={this.contentRef}
              context={context}
              {...this.props}
            />
          )}
        </CalendarContext.Consumer>
      );
    }
  }

  hoistNonReactStatic(CalendarConsumer, WrappedComponent);

  return CalendarConsumer;
}

export default asCalendarConsumer;
```

```js
/* ExpandableCalendar */
export default asCalendarConsumer(ExpandableCalendar);
```

- Is there a way to open ExpandableCalendar programmatically? Does the setPosition() function work or there's another way to do this.

### My Environment is

- `react-native-calendars@1.1266.0`:
- `react-native@0.64.2`:

Comment: in my case it gives me error saying ref does not exists on ExpandableCalendar.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround for this problem, this is not the best approach but it gets the job done.

You can use the react `key` prop to rerender the component every time the initial position is changed, this will force react to render the component again so it will look like it is closing and opening but without any animations.

```
 <ExpandableCalendar
        key={position}
        initialPosition={position}
        disablePan={true} //we need this
        disableWeekScroll={true}
      />
```

Example on press method for the toggle button

```
 onPress={() => {
           
            if (position === ExpandableCalendar.positions.CLOSED) {
              setPosition(ExpandableCalendar.positions.OPEN);
            } else {
              setPosition(ExpandableCalendar.positions.CLOSED);
            }
          }}
```

Comment: Am I getting it right, that you want to show or hide the Calendar by a click on a button?

Comment: Nope that's not the expected behavior he is asking how to expand and contract the calendar,  not showing and hiding.